# Win32 PostMessage and modern c++

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous

We currently have some code which relies heavily on the the following pattern:

1. UI thread needs work done
2. UI thread starts a thread which performs TaskA
3. Worker thread calls PostMessage(XXXXX_TASKA), lparam and wparam being specific to TaskA

This means for every "async" call we need to create another XXXX_TASKA, and then add a handler which knows how to interpret lparam and wparam. It seems like with lambdas there should be a better way to do this. I was thinking about creating a Task class, which contains a lambda for the continuation, and then using that for all async callbacks through the PostMessage interface. i.e. XXXXX_TASK_COMPLETE would be the only message we send, and the handler would always assume lparam is a pointer to a Task, and simply call the lambda.

Any ideas of pre-existing solutions like this?
Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3780.pdf

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm not sure what the article you posted has to do with my question. Can you clarify?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - Yeah, that's using very old C++ methodologies, which would require a new structure made for every function call. I would rather have something like a Task which would take two lambdas, one which would get launched when the task was run, and another when the task was complete, but on the UI thread.

Comment: The [Parallel Patterns Library (PPL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) would be an appropriate match for your requirements. In particular it allows you to run a task on another thread, but force the continuation onto a specific thread context (e.g. the GUI thread).

Comment: @bpeikes, my point is that it is a "pre-existing solution like this". Except it's using Command-derived classes and pointer-to-member. There might be "better ways" to do it, but there's nothing _wrong_ with it. It wouldn't take that much effort to make it use a `std::function` instead.